# I want to draw connected rectangular triangles

Tags: tkz-euclide

I want to draw a figure like this:

[image]

I was able to define points relatively to each other. So if I change my point A, B and C will automatically adapt.

My problem is my next point, that I would like to call D, so that I can connect B with D, and I can make my next triangle...

This is my code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=10, xmin=0,xmax=15]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzClip

    \tkzDefPoints{3/1/A};
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](0:6){B};
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](90:3){C};

    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{M};

    % driehoek 1
    \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C);
    \tkzDrawSegments[thick](A,B A,C B,C);
    \tkzLabelSegment[sloped](A,B){a};
    \tkzLabelSegment[sloped](B,C){b};
    \tkzLabelSegment[sloped](A,C){c};

    \draw[thick] (C) -- ($(C)!-4cm!-90:(B)$);


    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Resulting in this:

[image]

My question is their something like \tkzGetPoint{D} for my problem?

Or is there a tkzEuclid way to define my point D relatively to my point C.

Comment: Tkz-euclide refers to a Pythagorean triangle as triangles similar (homothetic) to triangle 3, 4 and 5. Which is not your case. You seem to want only rectangular triangles.

Comment: @AndréC Correct, I changed the title of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not speak French, so I cannot tell whether or not you can achieve this with `tkz-euclide`. But since you are already loading `calc`, why not using it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=10, xmin=0,xmax=15]
\tkzGrid
\tkzClip

\tkzDefPoints{3/1/A};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](0:6){B};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](90:3){C};

\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{M};

% driehoek 1
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C);
\tkzDrawSegments[thick](A,B A,C B,C);
\tkzLabelSegment[sloped](A,B){a};
\tkzLabelSegment[sloped](B,C){b};
\tkzLabelSegment[sloped](A,C){c};

\draw[thick] (C) -- ($(C)!4cm!90:(B)$) coordinate (H)
node[midway,sloped,below]{i}
-- ($(H)!3cm!-90:(C)$) coordinate (I)
node[midway,sloped,above]{d} -- (C)
node[midway,sloped,below]{h};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I make my documents with a lot of trial and error, so sometimes I don't know what exactly to use :)